# How to automate pulling data (KMZ? JSON?) from My Google Maps

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium-webdriver, geospatial, kmz

I am seeking a general approach as to how to automate the retrieval of data from a My Google Map.  While I could easily export any given layer to KML/KMZ, I'm looking for a way to do this within a larger script, that will automate the process.  Preferably, where I wouldn't even have to log in to the map itself to complete the data pull.

Two possible options I'm considering are 1) using Selenium/Beautiful Soup to simulate page-clicks on Google Maps and export the KMZ or 2) making use of Python Google Maps API.  Though, I'm not sure if this API makes it possible to download Google Maps layer via a script.

To be clear, the data is already in the map - I'm just looking for a way to export it.  It could either be a KMZ export, or better yet, GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

I used my browser’s inspection feature to figure out what was going on under the hood with the website I was interested in grabbing data from, which led me to this solution.

I use Selenium to login and navigate said website, then transfer my cookies to Python’s Requests package. I have Requests send a specific query to the server whose response is in the form of JSON. I was able to figure out what query to send and what form the response would be through the inspection feature previously stated. Once I have the response in JSON I use Python’s JSON package to convert into a Python dict to use however I need.

Sounds like you might not necessarily need Selenium but it does sound like the Requests package would be useful to your use case. I think your first step is figuring out what form the server response is when you interact with the website naturally to get what you want.

Hopefully this helps to some degree!